# How would you use an IF NOT statement but for 2 options

Tags: python

Sorry, I know my explanation isn't very good so I will show you the code

```
def game():
        level1 = input("You are stuck in the woods, lost after a school 
        trip, your phone is dead so you must make your way through the 
        woods. Do you turn left or right? ").lower()
        if level1 == "left":
            print("You turned left and a bear mauled you to death")
        elif level1 != "left" or level1 != "right":
            print("Please choose either left or right")
            game()
        elif level1 == "right":
            print("Level 2")
```

Sorry if it is not presented correctly or clearly. Whenever I type in "right" it comes up with "please choose left or right"

Comment: What is wrong about the code you provided?

Comment: Use `and` instead of `or`. Alternatively, change the entire condition to `elif level1 not in ["left", "right"]:`

Comment: A few ways to fix: One example: `if level1 == "left": .... elif level1 == "right": ... else: .... `

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the solution. The problem is in part :

```
elif level1 != "left" or level1 != "right":
```

Something isn't equal to left is right so when ever you type `right` it would pick the first logic

You must do something like:

```
if level1 == "left":
# Your code

elif level1 == "right":
# code

else:
# code
```

- but the EASIEST way is to put `And` instead of `or`

hope it is helpful

Answer (score 0):

I'd use an `if`, `elif`, `else`.

```
if level1 == "left":
    print("You turned left and a bear mauled you to death")
elif level1 == "right":
    print("Level 2")
elif level1 == "cheat": #We can use as many 'elif' as needed
    print("No Cheating...!")
else: #any other input #but only one 'else'
    print("Please choose either left or right")
    game()
```